# Modifying an old commit from a different branch

Tags: git, branch, branching-and-merging

I have a git repo with the branches as shown below:

```
                c5 (my branch 1)
               /
c1->c2->c3->c4/ (mainline)
```

After this I created another branch `my branch 2` from `my branch 1`. I have not yet committed anything in this new branch; all my changes are unstaged. If if I modify the c5 from `my branch 2` using `git commit -amend`, will the c5 of `my branch 1` also get modified?

If yes, is there any way I can make sure that it does not get modified? Essentially, I want my git repo to look like:

```
                c5 (my branch 1)
               /
c1->c2->c3->c4/ (mainline)
              \
               \ c5' (my branch 2)
```

But I have already created `my branch 2` on top of `my branch 1` and have written a lot of code after that in `my branch 1`.

Comment: When you amend C5, the new commit C5' is made. C5 is unchanged. The parent C4 gives birth to another child, a sibling of C5. C5' and C5 may look similar, but they are different commits. When you are on branch 2 and do the amend, branch 2 moves from C5 to C5' but branch 1 still points to C5. So branch 1 is not affected by the amend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, if you've created a branch the branch gets a new "reference" (a new git object is created). If you update your old commit using `--amend` also a new objects will be created, the old one won't be deleted.

After creating a new branch from a commit this branch is separated from any other branch. So changing commits or even the entire history of your branch `A` won't affect branch `B` in any way.

**This means** you can commit your changes on `my branch 2`, go back to `my branch 1` and amend the commit. You could also stash it and apply the changes on `my branch 1`. It basically doesn't matter what you do.